# Is it possible to make conditional sounds in a resourcepack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to change the Door sound depending on their wood. Is that possible with a resource pack?
I already know you can replace sounds. but can you make them conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a resource pack. As of 1.13.1, (the newest version of Minecraft as of this answer) all doors share the sounds `minecraft:block.wooden_door.open` and `minecraft:block.wooden_door.close`, which means that minecraft doesn't check the type of wood when it is deciding which noise to play.

Because of this, there's no way in the current game to use a resource pack to have unique sounds for the different wood door types.